# Cannot import cmap.io.gct: getting import error

Tags: python

I am trying to run a code which includes a line:

```
import cmap.io.gct as gct
```

But running this Python code is getting error because of that `cmap`.
The following error is like this:

```
File "bgedv2.py", line 6, in <module>
import cmap.io.gct as gct
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmap'
```

Can anyone tell me how to install `cmap.io.get` API on CentOS?

Comment: No idea what this library is, but see this issue: [link](https://github.com/cmap/cmapPy/issues/38). Looks like you are using old tutorial, and this import was deprecated. They have new tutorial though: [link](https://github.com/cmap/cmapPy/blob/master/tutorials/cmapPy_pandasGEXpress_tutorial.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

Download 
https://github.com/cmap/l1ktools/releases/tag/v1.1

l1ktools

and write python path

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/andrejeremcuk/Downloads/l1ktools-1.1/python
```

must work

```
import cmap.io.gct as gct
```